# proof that $x^2 - kxy + y^2 + x = 0$ doesnt have answer for infinite odd $k$ s.

Tags: number-theory

here is the solution:
let $d = gcd(x,y)$ so there exists $m,n$ such that: $gcd(m,n)=1$ and $y=nd$ and $x =md$

so we have:

$m^2 d^2 -kmnd^2 + n^2d^2 + md = 0$. so $d|m$. means that there exists $a$ such that $m=ad$. (I dont understand this part) so
$a^2d^4 - kand^3 +n^2d^2 + ad^2 = 0$. after omiting $d^2$ we can show that $a|n^2$ (I dont understand this part too).

but $gcd(m,n) = 1$ and $a|m$ so $a = 1$. we have:

$d^2-knd + n^2 + 1 = 0$.

(I will write the rest of the proof later, so you can think about it)

please help me with the two parts that I did not understand.

Comment: This has been edited to say $\gcd(m,n)=d$, but I think the OP intentionally wrote $\gcd(m,n)=1$, which is why I rejected the edit.

Comment: ohhh...I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the part $(I)$:
$$m^2d^2−kmnd^2+n^2d^2+md=0$$ Because of $d\neq 0$, we can get: $$m^2d−kmnd+n^2d+m=0$$ From here: $$m=d(-m^2+kmn-n^2)$$ Which means $d|m$.
For the part tow: $$a^2d^4−kand^3+n^2d^2+ad^2=0$$ We can write above equation as follow: $$a^2d^2−kand+n^2+a=0$$ Which we can get: $$n^2=-a(ad^2-knd+1)$$ So: $a|n^2$